# Types of property 'cacheLocation' are incompatible

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have an old app in react with javascript, but I started a new one, to slowly migrate the .JS code to Typescript.

The first file I want to migrate its a configuration file, when its .js build succeeds.

WHen renamed to .TS I get this error

```
/Users/xx/yy/lulo/src/adalConfig.ts
(13,54): Argument of type '{ tenant: string; clientId: string; endpoints: { api: string; }; 'apiUrl': string; cacheLocation: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AdalConfig'.
  Types of property 'cacheLocation' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"localStorage" | "sessionStorage" | undefined'
```

The file is this:

```
import { AuthenticationContext, adalFetch, withAdalLogin } from 'react-adal';

export const adalConfig = {
  tenant: 'xxxx-c220-48a2-a73f-1177fa2c098e',
  clientId: 'xxxxx-bd54-456d-8aa7-f8cab3147fd2',
  endpoints: {
    api:'xxxxx-abaa-4519-82cf-e9d022b87536'
  },
  'apiUrl': 'https://xxxxx-app.azurewebsites.net/api',
  cacheLocation: 'localStorage'
};

export const authContext = new AuthenticationContext(adalConfig);

export const adalApiFetch = (fetch, url, options) =>
  adalFetch(authContext, adalConfig.endpoints.api, fetch, adalConfig.apiUrl+url, options);

export const withAdalLoginApi = withAdalLogin(authContext, adalConfig.endpoints.api);
```

Comment: Try doing `cacheLocation: 'localStorage' as 'localStorage'`

Comment: lol that works, why? casting a string as a string?

Comment: please post as answer

Comment: Instead of ugly `'localStorage' as 'localStorage'` it's better to type the `adalConfig` properly: specify its type during declaration.

Comment: can you please explain how? in my case vscode had a hint and generated an index.d.ts file automatically.

Comment: `export const adalConfig: ...typenamehere.... = {`

Comment: Side remark: Typescript doesn't have "casts", only type assertions. And the reason it works is because the type of the object gets widened to string, but I assume the typing of the config only allows a type union of string literal types, so the widened type doesn't fit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the type of `adalConfig` gets *asserted* instead of being *defined*. You can read more about it [in the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) but it basically means that TypeScript *guesses* the type. Short example:

```
type FooBar = 'foo' | 'bar';
const fooBar1 = 'foo'; // fooBar1: 'foo'
const fooBar2: FooBar = 'foo'; // fooBar2: FooBar
```

[TypeScript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%2F%2F%20Not%20sure%20why%20null%20is%20accepted%20here%20when%20I've%20specified%20number%20as%20the%20type%0D%0Aconst%20foo%20%3D%20()%3A%20number%20%3D%3E%201%20%7C%7C%20null%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Even%20when%20enforcing%20non-nullable%0D%0Aconst%20foo2%20%3D%20()%3A%20NonNullable%3Cnumber%3E%20%3D%3E%201%20%7C%7C%20null%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Here%20tough%2C%20it%20works%3A%20null%20is%20not%20a%20number%0D%0Aconst%20foo3%20%3D%20(i%3A%20number)%3A%20number%20%3D%3E%20i%20%7C%7C%20null)

Type assertion depends on a whole bunch of stuff and it's really hard to guess *by hand* which type TypeScript is going to assert. It's really useful to write TS code quickly, though. In any case - the problem in your code is that `adalConfig.cacheLocation` gets asserted to a `string`, but instead you want TypeScript to understand that its type is compatible with `"localStorage" | "sessionStorage" | undefined`.

Two ways to do that:

1. `cacheLocation: 'localStorage' as 'localStorage'`: will precise to TypeScript that `cacheLocation` is of type `'localStorage'`, thus compatible with what you want
2. `export const adalConfig: AdalConfig = ...` will precise to TypeScript that the whole `adalConfig` object is of type `AdalConfig`, so it has basically the same effect

<sub>Kudos to [@explosion-pills](https://stackoverflow.com/users/454533/explosion-pills) and [@zerkms](https://stackoverflow.com/users/251311/zerkms) who contributed in the comments to this question</sub>

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an oldie but always helpful to post an update. You can import configuration from the msal library to set the type of the config variable.

```
import { MsalAuthProvider, LoginType  } from 'react-aad-msal';
import { Configuration } from 'msal';

// Msal Configurations
const config: Configuration = {
    auth: {
      authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/',
      clientId: '<YOUR APPLICATION ID>'
    },
    cache: {
      cacheLocation:"localStorage",
      storeAuthStateInCookie: true,
    }
  };

  // Authentication Parameters
  const authenticationParameters = {
    scopes: [
        `<your app registartion app id>/.default`
    ]
  }
   
  // Options
  const options = {
    loginType: LoginType.Popup,
    tokenRefreshUri: window.location.origin + '/auth.html'
  }

  export const authProvider = new MsalAuthProvider(config, authenticationParameters, options)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { CacheLocation } from "@auth0/auth0-react";

const AUTH0_CASH_LOCATION: CacheLocation | unefined = "localstorage";
```

this will help you. Auth0 provider makes sure that caching should save in memory or localStorage so you should provide either localStorage or memory for cacheLocation option